# Unable to pass JSON object in body to WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have an MVC 4 project containing a simple WebAPI2 controller. I'm trying to pass it data encoded as JSON within the POST body.

```
Public Class ClientController
    Inherits ApiController

    <AllowAnonymous>
    <HttpPost>
    <Route("api/Client/")>
    Public Function Post(<FromBody> entry As LogEntry) As HttpResponseMessage

        Try
            Dim lld As New LoginLogsEntities
            lld.sp_insertofflineloginaudit(entry.Hostname, entry.ClientName, entry.SessionID, entry.EventAction, entry.EventDateTime)
            Return New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End Try

    End Function

End Class
```

And the LogEntry class:

```
Public Class LogEntry
    Private _EventDateTime As DateTime
    Private _OSVersion As String
    Private _Hostname As String
    Private _SessonID As String
    Private _EventAction As String
    Private _Username As String
    Private _ClientName As String

    <JsonProperty("EventDateTime")>
    Public Property EventDateTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return _EventDateTime
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
            _EventDateTime = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <JsonProperty("OSVersion")>
    Public Property OSVersion() As String
        Get
            Return _OSVersion
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _OSVersion = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <JsonProperty("Hostname")>
    Public Property Hostname() As String
        Get
            Return _Hostname
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Hostname = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <JsonProperty("SessionID")>
    Public Property SessionID() As String
        Get
            Return _SessonID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _SessonID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <JsonProperty("EventAction")>
    Public Property EventAction() As String
        Get
            Return _EventAction
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _EventAction = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <JsonProperty("Username")>
    Public Property Username() As String
        Get
            Return _Username
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Username = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <JsonProperty("ClientName")>
    Public Property ClientName() As String
        Get
            Return _ClientName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _ClientName = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

On the client side, I've tried a couple of things. the raw JSON included in the body is:

```
{
    "EventDateTime":"2022-08-19T04:02:51.3512145Z",
    "OSVersion":"10.0.19044",
    "Hostname":"comp",
    "SessionID":"E1B60C64B1",
    "Event":"Lock",
    "Username":"bob"
}
```

I've tried sending the request from PowerShell and using Boomerang (an Edge clone of Postman) but in all cases, while the post entry point is hit, the parameter is null. PowerShell code as below:

```
invoke-webrequest -Uri http://localhost:54321/api/Client -Method Post -Body $event -ContentType "application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved; the JSON being passed was not valid. The Username parameter (before I edited it for this question), contained a domain name and username. The backslash was not correctly escaped.